Restore task failing in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I am using .NET SDK 8.0 and .NET8.0 with Visual Studio 17.10 on my build agent (self hosted agent I created on on-prem server).
Now I have created CI Pipeline in Azure DevOps with Restore,Build,Publish,Publish Artifatcts steps, using Classic editor and selecting ASP.NET Core template.
The Restore step is failing with below error.

C:\agent_work\2\s\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets (>= 1.20.1)' for 'net8.0'.
C:\agent_work\2\s\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 6.4.0)' for 'net8.0'.

How to resolve this?




Are you using nuget.org or custom feed?

Did you upgrade your projects to .NET 8? Are the corresponding nuget packages up-to-date?

@SankarMantripragada - I am using nuget.org

@RuiJarimba - I got the Dotnet project from the Developers, I am just creating CICD for the same.

According to the MS documentation, VS v17.1 does not support .net8.0 so this may (or may not) be affecting it. To target net8.0, you must use version 17.8 or later.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/version-requirements
